# Can someone explain why a 8 years old hardware appear to be fast as a newer i5 notebook?

Tags: hardware

I have a (quite) new Acer 7750G Notebbok (Intel Core i5 2410M, 4 GB DDR3 1333 MHz, Intel HM65 Express Chipset) running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.
I gave to a friend of mine my older Desktop PC (Asus Termninator T2-AE1, Amd Athlon 64 3200+, 1.5 GB DDR 333 MHz, K8ST Chipset) previously running Windows XP now proudly running Ubuntu 10.04.

I cannot explain why that old piece of hardware run almost fast as mine.
Is Linux that miraculous? :-)

Comment: Answer to the miraculous part: You have to see a linux installation without a desktop environment which is the main resource hog.

Answer (score 1):

It may run the basic system fast enough, but when the time to perform a more computational intensive activity comes, the newer system's superiority will become obvious. Also take in mind that linux is not windows. A basic linux system can run fine on a vast variety of hardware, dated or not.

Comment: Indeed, Linux can perform decently on older hardware which is agonizingly slow running Windows.

Comment: My thoughts exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu doesn't have much high requirements, and the specifications of your Desktop PC is more than enough to run Ubuntu flawless. Linux contrarely to Windows, isn't a resource hog, so it's perfectly normal that Ubuntu would run great on that desktop PC.

[The official requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements/) for Ubuntu 11.04 are:

700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)

512 MiB RAM (system memory)

5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an 
alternative approach)

VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution

And your PC is better than this.